# The type android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Extender cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-appcompat, urbanairship.com

I just upgraded UrbanAirship to latest version am getting below build issue for latest library

The type android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Extender cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have added v4 support library too able to import import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

Comment: How you added the support library, by putting this  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0+'` in the dependencies on your gradle file?

Comment: Am not using Gradle. added jar to build path from libs folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an out of date v4 support library. Make sure to update your Android SDK and re-add the v4 support library jar file.